# Displaying a Toast When the Message is Successfully Sent from android in-built

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to Display a Toast When the Message is Successfully Sent from android in-built app.
but i not found any satisfactory result over the internet.
Please help me out with some useful links.

Comment: sorry. there is no broadcast receiver for sms sent due to its usage of `SMSManager` class.

Comment: Thanks for response, but i am not getting what i am looking for . i also went through Mike M link but its not work for me.help me out with showing toast on sending sms from android inbuilt app.thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks !!!@ Mike M link works exactly i am looking for ...Thanks a ton...

Answer (score 1):

Use PendingIntent object to monitor the status of the SMS:

```
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(SENT), 0);
```

And Broadcast Receiver objects to display a Toast:

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));
```

Refer this link for more details,it may help you:http://mobiforge.com/design-development/sms-messaging-android

Comment: thanks for your response but the link actually using smsmanager class which is used for sending sms from your own app bt i am looking for displaying toast when i send sms from android inbuilt sms app.please help out with that relavence.